# xfce4: resizable panel separators?

Tags: xfce, panel, widgets

Is there a way to have resizable separators on the panel in XFCE4?

We either have a very narrow, fixed-width separator, or else we have one that is expandable, which means that it expands to the maximum size possible.

I would like to have the option of resizing panel separators to an absolute width, so that I can configure the amount of space between the widgets on the panel.

This is possible in Plasma and probably other environments, and I'm looking for a way to do this under XFCE4.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Doesn't look like that might be configurable.  Maybe consider the suggestion from here:  https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=9127

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess creating multiple panels is the only way.